# Binding vue components to class name

Tags: vue.js

Alright so I am trying to bind this vue components to a class name so it triggers on every element that has this class but what happens is that it only works with the first element and not with other ones

```
<div class="__comment_post"> 
    <textarea></textarea> 
    <input type="submit" v-on:click="submitComment" /> <!-- submit comment being only triggered on this one -->
</div>


<div class="__comment_post">
    <textarea></textarea> 
    <input type="submit" v-on:click="submitComment" />
</div>


<div class="__comment_post">
    <textarea></textarea> 
    <input type="submit" v-on:click="submitComment" />
</div>
```

As you can see above, I've got 3 divs with class __comment_post so naturally submitComment should be bound to all these 3 divs but what happens is that submitComment is being triggered only on the first one

```
var app = new Vue({

    el:".__comment_post",
    data: {
        comment: ""
    },


    methods: {
        submitComment: function() {
            console.log("Test");
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little example you and others can follow in order to bind vue instance to class names.
Lets say, you would like to bind Vue to multiple existing `<div class="comment">` element in HTML.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="comment" data-id="1">

<div>

<div class="comment" data-id="2">

<div>
```

*Now, you can try the following logic/code to your example.*

**JS**:

```
var comments = {
  "1": {"content": "Comment 1"},
  "2": {"content": "Comment 2"}
}

$('.comment').each(function () {
  var $el = $(this)

  var id = $el.attr('data-id')
  var data = comments[id]

  new Vue({
    el: this,
    data: data,
    template: '<div class="comment">{{ content }}<div>'
  })
})
```

I hope this will answer your question :)

Comment: His question was why it works with the first element and not with others. First line of my answers that....

Comment: I appreciate the solution. This is what I came here for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The vue instance is mounted on the **first** found DOM element with the css selector passed to the `el` option. So the rest two `div` have no vue instances mounted on them.

So wrap your divs with a wrapper `div` and mount the vue instance on that wrapper

```
<div id="app">
<div class="__comment_post"> 
    <textarea></textarea> 
    <input type="submit" v-on:click="submitComment" /> <!-- submit comment being only triggered on this one -->
</div>


<div class="__comment_post">
    <textarea></textarea> 
    <input type="submit" v-on:click="submitComment" />
</div>


<div class="__comment_post">
    <textarea></textarea> 
    <input type="submit" v-on:click="submitComment" />
</div>
```

**script**

```
var app = new Vue({

    el:"#app",
    data: {
        comment: ""
    },


    methods: {
        submitComment: function() {
            console.log("Test");
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. It's just a solution.